# Как мне осуществить переход между экранами? onTouch требует сделать метод onClick() static, но я не могу его сделать таковым

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import space.kozachok.a2048.MainView.*;

class InputListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    //MainActivityGame exmp = new MainActivityGame();
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 0;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 25;
    private static final int MOVE_THRESHOLD = 250;
    private static final int RESET_STARTING = 10;
    private final MainView mView;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float lastDx;
    private float lastDy;
    private float previousX;
    private float previousY;
    private float startingX;
    private float startingY;
    private int previousDirection = 1;
    private int veryLastDirection = 1;
    // Whether or not we have made a move, i.e. the blocks shifted or tried to shift.
    private boolean hasMoved = false;
    // Whether or not we began the press on an icon. This is to disable swipes if the user began
    // the press on an icon.
    public static boolean home = false;
    public static boolean beganOnIcon = false;
    public Drawable backgroundRectangle = MainView.backgroundRectangle;
    public InputListener(MainView view) {
        super();
        this.mView = view;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                startingX = x;
                startingY = y;
                previousX = x;
                previousY = y;
                lastDx = 0;
                lastDy = 0;
                hasMoved = false;
                beganOnIcon = iconPressed(mView.sXNewGame, mView.sYIcons)
                              || iconPressed(mView.sXUndo, mView.sYIcons)
                              || iconPressed(mView.sXHome, mView.sYIcons);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                if (mView.game.isActive() && !beganOnIcon) {
                    float dx = x - previousX;
                    if (Math.abs(lastDx + dx) < Math.abs(lastDx) + Math.abs(dx) && Math.abs(dx) > RESET_STARTING
                            && Math.abs(x - startingX) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        startingX = x;
                        startingY = y;
                        lastDx = dx;
                        previousDirection = veryLastDirection;
                    }
                    if (lastDx == 0) {
                        lastDx = dx;
                    }
                    float dy = y - previousY;
                    if (Math.abs(lastDy + dy) < Math.abs(lastDy) + Math.abs(dy) && Math.abs(dy) > RESET_STARTING
                            && Math.abs(y - startingY) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        startingX = x;
                        startingY = y;
                        lastDy = dy;
                        previousDirection = veryLastDirection;
                    }
                    if (lastDy == 0) {
                        lastDy = dy;
                    }
                    if (pathMoved() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE * SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && !hasMoved) {
                        boolean moved = false;
                        //Vertical
                        if (((dy >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dy) >= Math.abs(dx)) || y - startingY >= MOVE_THRESHOLD) && previousDirection % 2 != 0) {
                            moved = true;
                            previousDirection = previousDirection * 2;
                            veryLastDirection = 2;
                            mView.game.move(2);
                        } else if (((dy <= -SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dy) >= Math.abs(dx)) || y - startingY <= -MOVE_THRESHOLD) && previousDirection % 3 != 0) {
                            moved = true;
                            previousDirection = previousDirection * 3;
                            veryLastDirection = 3;
                            mView.game.move(0);
                        }
                        //Horizontal
                        if (((dx >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dx) >= Math.abs(dy)) || x - startingX >= MOVE_THRESHOLD) && previousDirection % 5 != 0) {
                            moved = true;
                            previousDirection = previousDirection * 5;
                            veryLastDirection = 5;
                            mView.game.move(1);
                        } else if (((dx <= -SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dx) >= Math.abs(dy)) || x - startingX <= -MOVE_THRESHOLD) && previousDirection % 7 != 0) {
                            moved = true;
                            previousDirection = previousDirection * 7;
                            veryLastDirection = 7;
                            mView.game.move(3);
                        }
                        if (moved) {
                            hasMoved = true;
                            startingX = x;
                            startingY = y;
                        }
                    }
                }
                previousX = x;
                previousY = y;
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                previousDirection = 1;
                veryLastDirection = 1;
                //"Menu" inputs
                if (!hasMoved) {
                    if (iconPressed(mView.sXNewGame, mView.sYIcons)) {
                        //alpha
                        if (!mView.game.gameLost()) {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(mView.getContext())
                                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.reset, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            mView.game.newGame();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.continue_game, null)
                                    .setTitle(R.string.reset_dialog_title)
                                    .setMessage(R.string.reset_dialog_message)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            mView.game.newGame();
                        }

                    } else if (iconPressed(mView.sXUndo, mView.sYIcons)) {
                        //alpha
                        mView.game.revertUndoState();
                    } else if (iconPressed(mView.sXHome, mView.sYIcons)) {
                        //alpha
                        beganOnIcon = true;
                        //MainActivityGame.this.onClick();
                        //exmp.onClick();
                    } else if (isTap(2) && inRange(mView.startingX, x, mView.endingX)
                            && inRange(mView.startingY, x, mView.endingY) && mView.continueButtonEnabled) {
                        mView.game.setEndlessMode();
                    }
                }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private float pathMoved() {
        return (x - startingX) * (x - startingX) + (y - startingY) * (y - startingY);
    }

    private boolean iconPressed(int sx, int sy) {
        return isTap(1) && inRange(sx, x, sx + mView.iconSize)
                && inRange(sy, y, sy + mView.iconSize);
    }

    private boolean inRange(float starting, float check, float ending) {
        return (starting <= check && check <= ending);
    }

    private boolean isTap(int factor) {
        return pathMoved() <= mView.iconSize * mView.iconSize * factor;
    }

}
```

---

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivityGame extends AppCompatActivity {



    private long backPressedTime;
    private static final String WIDTH = "width";
    private static final String HEIGHT = "height";
    private static final String SCORE = "score";
    private static final String HIGH_SCORE = "high score temp";
    private static final String UNDO_SCORE = "undo score";
    private static final String CAN_UNDO = "can undo";
    private static final String UNDO_GRID = "undo";
    private static final String GAME_STATE = "game state";
    private static final String UNDO_GAME_STATE = "undo game state";
    private MainView view;


    /*public static void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityGame.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void  onBackPressed() {
        onClick();
        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }


    public void onClick (){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view = new MainView(this);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        view.hasSaveState = settings.getBoolean("save_state", false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasState")) {
                load();
            }
        }
        setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            //Do nothing
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
            view.game.move(2);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
            view.game.move(0);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
            view.game.move(3);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
            view.game.move(1);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("hasState", true);
        save();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        save();
    }

    private void save() {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        Tile[][] field = view.game.grid.field;
        Tile[][] undoField = view.game.grid.undoField;
        editor.putInt(WIDTH, field.length);
        editor.putInt(HEIGHT, field.length);
        for (int xx = 0; xx < field.length; xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < field[0].length; yy++) {
                if (field[xx][yy] != null) {
                    editor.putInt(xx + " " + yy, field[xx][yy].getValue());
                } else {
                    editor.putInt(xx + " " + yy, 0);
                }

                if (undoField[xx][yy] != null) {
                    editor.putInt(UNDO_GRID + xx + " " + yy, undoField[xx][yy].getValue());
                } else {
                    editor.putInt(UNDO_GRID + xx + " " + yy, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        editor.putLong(SCORE, view.game.score);
        editor.putLong(HIGH_SCORE, view.game.highScore);
        editor.putLong(UNDO_SCORE, view.game.lastScore);
        editor.putBoolean(CAN_UNDO, view.game.canUndo);
        editor.putInt(GAME_STATE, view.game.gameState);
        editor.putInt(UNDO_GAME_STATE, view.game.lastGameState);
        editor.commit();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        load();
    }


    private void load() {
        //Stopping all animations
        view.game.aGrid.cancelAnimations();

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        for (int xx = 0; xx < view.game.grid.field.length; xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < view.game.grid.field[0].length; yy++) {
                int value = settings.getInt(xx + " " + yy, -1);
                if (value > 0) {
                    view.game.grid.field[xx][yy] = new Tile(xx, yy, value);
                } else if (value == 0) {
                    view.game.grid.field[xx][yy] = null;
                }

                int undoValue = settings.getInt(UNDO_GRID + xx + " " + yy, -1);
                if (undoValue > 0) {
                    view.game.grid.undoField[xx][yy] = new Tile(xx, yy, undoValue);
                } else if (value == 0) {
                    view.game.grid.undoField[xx][yy] = null;
                }
            }
        }

        view.game.score = settings.getLong(SCORE, view.game.score);
        view.game.highScore = settings.getLong(HIGH_SCORE, view.game.highScore);
        view.game.lastScore = settings.getLong(UNDO_SCORE, view.game.lastScore);
        view.game.canUndo = settings.getBoolean(CAN_UNDO, view.game.canUndo);
        view.game.gameState = settings.getInt(GAME_STATE, view.game.gameState);
        view.game.lastGameState = settings.getInt(UNDO_GAME_STATE, view.game.lastGameState);
    }

}
```

Comment: В код не вчитывался, но, возможно, вам надо просто MainActivityGame заменить на view?

Comment: Не работает, view не имеет такого метода

Comment: Может тогда MainActivityGame.this.onClick()?

Comment: not an enclosing class: MainActivityGame

Comment: Я пытался сделать экземпляр MainActivityGame, но при нажатие на кнопку приложение вылитает, мне кажеться это связанно с тем что в onClick() я пытаюсь закрить MainActivityGame

Comment: Видимо просто не получится. Показывайте вообще весь код с подробным объяснением того что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: else if (iconPressed(mView.sXHome, mView.sYIcons)) {
                        //alpha
                        beganOnIcon = true;
                        //MainActivityGame.this.onClick();
                        //exmp.onClick();                                                                                                                         Это условие отвечает за нажатие клавишы я хочу сделать так чтобы когда оно выполняеться то событие MainActivGame завершылось и начиналось MainActiv (то есть поменять экран)

Comment: Могу дать быстрое и неправильное решение) Неправильное в смысле красоты кода, архитектуры etc. Вот оно: `((MainActivityGame) mView.getContext()).onClick();`

Comment: Огромное Спасибо, Я два дня ломал голову (решил изучить java за лето и сразу пробывать писать поэтому там до красоты очень далеко)

Comment: Был рад помочь)